# Data structure choice for dynamic programming

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

In order to implement a DP algorithm for detecting whether a word is breakable into sub-words of length 'n' to 1, what should be the choice of data structure for caching DP results.
**Example:** **the word 'pita' can be broken into 'pit', 'it' & 'i' which are all valid dictionary words as well**.
The DP algorithm should detect such words.

I can imagine I need start from words of length 1 and build up substrings of increasing lengths but I am not able to arrive at a data structure which can efficiently store the subproblem's results

Comment: ArrayList would fit on this that it would increase automatically

Comment: What the function return? Number of way to split, or just is there any valid split? or a collection of valid splits?

Comment: It should just be a bool saying whether the word was breakable into all lengths from n to 1. For 'pita' it would be 'true' but for the word 'are' - the return value should be 'false'

Comment: So it should be `boolean[]dp` , with dp[i] means starting from i, is the substring from i has a valid split, the final result is in dp[0]

Comment: does `tip` also work ? or changing char position is not allowed ?

Answer (score 1):

if you work on your word sequential you don't need to track previous word as you don't reach them again, but you can use a cache to cache previously lookup sub word in the dictionary.
If i understand the problem, then i think the following Java code may help you:

```
String term = "pita";
Set<String> dictionary = new HashSet<String>();
boolean ans = true;
for(int i = 0; i < term.length() && ans == true; i++) {
    for(int j = i + 1; j < term.length(); j++) {
        String subTerm = term.substring(i, j);
        if(!dictionary.contains(subTerm)){
            ans = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("ans [" = ans + "]");
```

For dictionary you can use a hash table and it support to take O(1) to check if the sub
word exist or not. if you cache previously checked sub word it will take the same O(1)

I think this problem is fitted in **sorting and searching** technique not in DP because
it did not use a previous answer to produce current answer.

Comment: First, the inner loop will check for every pair (i,j), starting at i, if one of those pairs is not in the dictionary, the result will be false. So your code just check for every substring in the `term`, are all of them in the dictionary, which is not correct. Second, the syntax for substring(start, end) is wrong, it should be term.substring(i, j + 1), you just try to see the different.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for special datastructure as such a boolean DP array would be sufficient :-

> isSentence[j] tell the substring str[j to n] is valid concatenation of
>   english words/word where n is last index
>
> isSentence[j] = or(isword(str[j to i]) && isSentece[i+1]) for all i
>   from j to n
>
> or here means logical OR of all subproblem and isword is dictionary
>   lookup which returns boolean value and && logical AND

Answer (score 0):

> I can imagine I need start from words of length 1 and build up substrings of increasing lengths but I am not able to arrive at a data structure which can efficiently store the subproblem's results

The following is a pseudo-code written in **Java** *might not compile*

**TrieNode.java**

```
class TrieNode
{
    public TrieNode (double a, double b, double g, int size)
    {
        this.alpha = a;
        this.beta = b;
        this.gamma = g;
        this.next = new TrieNode [size];
    }
    public double alpha, beta, gamma;
    public TrieNode [] next;
}
```

You can replace `alpha`, `beta`, `gamma` with your parameters for the problem.

**Trie.java**

```
class Trie
{

    private TrieNode root;
    private char base;
    private final int ALPHABET_SIZE;

    public Trie (int ALPHABET_SIZE, char base_char)
    {
        this.base = base_char;
        this.root=new TrieNode(0,0,0,ALPHABET_SIZE);
    }

    public boolean insert (String word, double [] param)
    {
        TrieNode current = this.root;
        int i = (-1);

        if (!validate(word))
            return false;

        char [] c = word.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < (c.length-1); i++)
        {
            if (current.next[c[i]-base] == null)
                current.next[c[i]-base] = new TrieNode (0,0,0,ALPHABET_SIZE);
            current = current.next[c[i]-base];
        }

        if (current.next[c[i]-base] == null)
            current.next[c[i]-base] = new TrieNode (0,0,0,ALPHABET_SIZE);

        current.next[c[i]-base].alpha = param[0];
        current.next[c[i]-base].beta = param[1];
        current.next[c[i]-base].gamma = param[2];
        return true;
    }

    public boolean validate (String word)
    {
        for (char c : word.toCharArray())
            if (c < base || c > (base+ALPHABET_SIZE-1))
                return false;
    }

}
```

This is an index-based Trie, with safe insert function.

**MappedTrie.java**

```
class MappedTrie
{
    public final char [] ALPHABET;
    private Trie trie;

    MappedTrie (char [] alphabet)
    {
        ALPHABET = alphabet;
        trie = new Trie (ALPHABET.length,0);
    }

    public boolean insert (String word, double [] param)
    {
        if (!validate(word))
            return false;

        String key = "";

        for (char c : word.toCharArray())
            key += encode(c);

        return trie.insert(key,param);

    }

    private char encode (char c)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<ALPHABET.length; i++)
            if (c == ALPHABET[i])
                return i;
    }

    private char decode (char d)
    {
        return ALPHABET[d];
    }

    public boolean validate (String word)
    {
        boolean exist = false;

        for (char c : word.toCharArray())
        {
            exist = false;
            for (char d : ALPHABET) if (c == d) { exist = true; break; }
            if (!exist) return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

In case of a custom alphabet where characters are not adjecent, we can map it over index.

**Test**

```
class Test
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        // 'a'+0, 'a'+1, 'a'+2
        MappedTrie k = new MappedTrie(3, 'a');

        k.insert("aa", { 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 });
        k.insert("ab", { 0.4, 0.5, 0.6 });
        k.insert("ac", { 0.7, 0.8, 0.9 });

        k.insert("ba", { 0.01, 0.02, 0.03 });
        k.insert("bb", { 0.04, 0.05, 0.06 });
        k.insert("bc", { 0.07, 0.08, 0.09 });

        k.insert("ca", { 0.001, 0.002, 0.003 });
        k.insert("cb", { 0.004, 0.005, 0.006 });
        k.insert("cc", { 0.007, 0.008, 0.009 });

        // 'a' => 0, 'b' => 1, 'c' => 2
        MappedTrie t = new MappedTrie({'a','b','c'});

        t.insert("aa", { 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 });
        t.insert("ab", { 0.4, 0.5, 0.6 });
        t.insert("ac", { 0.7, 0.8, 0.9 });

        t.insert("ba", { 0.01, 0.02, 0.03 });
        t.insert("bb", { 0.04, 0.05, 0.06 });
        t.insert("bc", { 0.07, 0.08, 0.09 });

        t.insert("ca", { 0.001, 0.002, 0.003 });
        t.insert("cb", { 0.004, 0.005, 0.006 });
        t.insert("cc", { 0.007, 0.008, 0.009 });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using `unordered_map<string, int>` or `unordered_set<string>` might be very helpful.